# Android: Is there a way to execute JavaScript from my app?

Tags: javascript, android

I was hoping to find something in the Android sdk similar to the `javax.script` package in Java; but haven't been able to find anything.  Am I missing a way to execute JavaScript from my app?

Comment: What rights would you expect it to have?  What is the script actually doing?

Comment: Why can't you do whatever the script is doing right there in Java?

Comment: I want to be able to let users execute a script.  Their scripts will interact with interfaces which I will implement in Java. (that makes sense, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rhino is a port of JavaScript that is implemented in Java. It can run on Android with minor tweaks. You can find the code for it as part of the [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) project.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed an invisible browser and have it execute the script.  But perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute JavaScript from within a `WebView`. Make sure you set `WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`.

You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you need the JavaScript to do. There is a way to execute JavaScript contained within HTML, ie PhoneGap.

Comment: can u give me an example plz?