# Running a javascript file within Java (Android)

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have a website that I want to log into from an android app and in order to submit the POST request with right information, they need some hashed values. The way that the website does it is through a javascript file. I tried tracing through it but I couldn't get the same result as the native website.

So i've decided to download their javascript file and run it within java.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to run specific methods within their file.

Here's my code so far and it's extremely bare bones.

```
public void hashIt(String valueForMethod1, String valueForMethod2){
    final ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    try {
        engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("res/raw/theirFile.js"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374016/how-to-execute-javascript-on-android

Comment: Why not write your own hash?  The original has already been comprised by virtue of the fact that it resides in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Invocable` to invoke a method of the Javascript that has been loaded

```
Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
inv.invokeFunction("foo", "bar"); // invoke foo("bar")
```

See this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#invoke) for a deeper introduction

**Edit**

As stated by Morrison Chang, apparently there is no `javax.script` namespace on Android, so you may check the thread he gave a link to in its comment.

Comment: Android Java has no javax.script namespace - therefore no Invocable

Comment: @MorrisonChang didn't knew about that, thank you :) Edited with your comment.

Comment: Although it is true that Android Java does not have it natively, it is possible to import the jar of javax.script, which is what I did :)

Comment: @Rei If you are using Rhino/ASE or your own Javascript engine you should add that to your question.