# Loading a web page in android application to execute javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using a WebView in the android activity to load a web page when the activity created .
The main reason is to execute javascript code from android . I do not have a good knowledge in android programming so after some googling I found this question :[How to execute JavaScript on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374016/how-to-execute-javascript-on-android)

I created a project and tried the solution but error is occuring when initializing the activity. 
This is the code  in the activity :

```
  package com.example.test;

  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.webkit.WebView;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
   //       myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


}

public Activity getActivity() {
    Log.i("TAG", "getting activity");
    return this;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

This the code in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.test"
     android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/webview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name="com.example.DialogActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BgService" />

    </application>


 </manifest>
```

This is the error :

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     
    ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: 
   java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any Help please bout the error?

Comment: dont define the webview in the manifest but in the activity layout .And set the layout in the activity with setContentView()

Answer (score 1):

```
You not set your View 

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

in web view You can use method

in oncreate You put that code

```
 WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

if work than vote up..
Thanks