# Access java script function from JS file placed in asset folder in android without any html or webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I've placed javascript file in asset folder. How to call javascript function on click of button in activity. I need to show encrypted and decrypted text returned by js function in TextView so don't want to use webview. Please give me solution either for webview as well if its the only possibility.

Here is code for my js file

```
function encrypt(string, key, iv){
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv);
return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key, {
                            iv: iv,
                            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
                            }).toString();}

function decrypt(string, key, iv){
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv);
return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(string, key, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,  iv : iv}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);}
```

Looking forward for solution, Thanks.

Comment: have a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418086/7835745

Comment: Note that the project suggested by that answer has been deprecated in favor of LiquidCore: https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore