# call javascript method in .js file inside android studio assets

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin

I am using a library called matrix.org

[image]

there are some javascript files in this library that contains some methods

is it possible to call these method inside native java or kotlin code of android studio ?

Comment: Related: [How to execute JavaScript on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8374016/295004)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enable JavaScript

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

To call JavaScript method you have to use `evaluateJavascript(..)` method

```
    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: " + "getValue(\"message\")", new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onReceive");
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + value);
        }
    });
```

And your JavaScript method is like

```
function getValue(msg) {
    return 10;
}
```