# Can an android app run javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, android, post, html-post

I am posting a username and password to a webpage and as a response im getting html code for an error that basically says that i need javascript to run the page. Is there a way to get an android app to run javascript?

Comment: You can make the webview support javascript. Use webview.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374016/how-to-execute-javascript-on-android n http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042710/android-is-there-a-way-to-execute-javascript-from-my-app

Answer (score 0):

i have never tried to do an android apliction but yes you can create one with html css and javascript, i recomend you to see this video from a chanel that i think is real good

https://youtu.be/eJa8xie9WZs

Comment: if u want to add javascript to a app that u have already created i dont know how to help, sry